# I need to test my android application on a 7'' tablet

Tags: android

Can some one please give me the details for creating an avd 
I am using the following:

```
Abstracted  LCD Density :240
max VM Application heap size :24
Device Ram :512
Skin :BuiltinWVGA800
SDcard size 512
Target :2.3.3
API level 10
```

Also in my Manifest File:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

Please dont redirect me to another URL because i havent found much help.If possible give me the configuration details for creating a avd or changes i need to make in manifest file .i need to make to run the application on a 7' tablet.Thanks.

Comment: *"Please dont redirect me to another URL because i havent found much help."*  Ummm, but what if the link is the answer?  Hyperlinks power the web.  Wait until someone gives an answer with a link you've already seen (and/or that doesn't solve your problem) to offer a critique...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's is no one set of specs for `7" tablet`. You can mimic certain device by cloning its parameters but `7" tablet` does not really mean any particular set of params to answer your question (i.e. you assumed that density is 240DPI which is wrong - I got some 10" tables with 160 DPI for example). Same for screen resolution - it can be 800x480 or 1280x800 - and still be 7". So pick up any exact 7" tablet and check its specification and create similar AVD

Comment: Thanks WebnetMobile.com Will try this.